# Bluetooth module attribute error

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to make a Bluetooth controlled raspberry pi car. I installed all the modules and packages to get started with Bluetooth. I also wrote a program for the car.

After running the program I get this error:

```
server_sock =bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
AttributeError : 'module' object has no attribute 'BluetoothSocket'
```

What does this mean?

Do you think I installed the packages incorrectly? Well it gave me errors while installing the packages.

Here is the code

```
import bluetooth
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)

def Blink(numTimes,speed):
  for i in range(0,numTimes):
    GPIO.output(18,True)
    print "Blinking " + str(i+1)
    time.sleep(speed)
    GPIO.output(18,False)
    time.sleep(speed)
    print ("Done Blinking LED")

server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 1
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

while True:
  data = client_sock.recv(1024)
  print "received [%s]" % data
  if (data == "1"):
    print ("LED ON")
    GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
  if (data == "0"):
    print ("LED OFF")
    GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
  if (data == "5"):
    print ("LED Blink")
    Blink(10,0.1)
  if (data == "e"):
    print ("Exit")
    break

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to comment yet, so I'm posting this "answer" to ask for clarification. We need more context and source code. BlueZ is very tricky to deal with and makes a *huge* difference if you're using BlueZ 5 vs BlueZ 4 or older. Also, there's `dbus` methods and `bluetoothctl` methods and `hciconfig` methods of accessing the bluetooth device.

This is a topic that interests me because I am currently working on a project with bluetooth and have dealt with many problems. The method I used is based on the one at http://blog.fraggod.net/2015/03/28/bluetooth-pan-network-setup-with-bluez-5x.html because it worked best.

Your error means that you are attempting to access the "BluetoothSocket" attribute of a "BluetoothSocket" which makes no sense. I can't say more without more context though.

Comment: Thanks Jon M, Can you also tell me in order what to do to make bluetooth fully functional in the pi , i would really appreciate if u told all the packages to install and pairing and all that, by the way i am using raspberry pi 3

Comment: Thanks Jon M, Can you also tell me in order what to do to make bluetooth fully functional in the pi , i would really appreciate if u told all the packages to install and pairing and all that, by the way i am using raspberry pi 3

Comment: That's a whole subject by itself, and not appropriate for this comment format.. Pair the devices first. You only have to do that once (hopefully). Here's a tutorial: http://lifehacker.com/everything-you-need-to-set-up-bluetooth-on-the-raspberr-1768482065 then establish a PAN to network between your Pi and another Bluetooth device. To make your Pi the server, use this tutorial: http://blog.fraggod.net/2015/03/28/bluetooth-pan-network-setup-with-bluez-5x.html unless you want a different type of bluetooth connection like serial, A2DP or whatever. That's different.

Comment: Thanks Jon , so do u think I won't get that syntax error I got (it's in my question)

Comment: I meant won't I get the syntax error after following the likehacker article

Comment: The syntax error is in your code. It will still be there. The lifehacker article just explains how to pair devices, which is a one-time thing. The other tutorial describes how to network between two paired bluetooth devices. I can't help you with your code because you haven't disclosed enough of it.

Comment: K I am away from my house i. I'll   send  the code as I get there

Comment: ok i have paired my phone with the pi, i have also installed all the packages from programming bluetooth and everything. so now what should i do . i am going to 'bluetooth serial controller' to control the car via bluetooth so how should i set it up. i want it to work like this>whenever i press a button in the app let's says forwards button which sends a character 'F' then back in my program when ever 'F' is recieved it should perform the code under it (go forwards) . how can i do it.

Comment: by the way when i did the pairing it said Paired: Yes,Connected: No,Trusted : Yes. it isnt connected will this affect anything .

Comment: i have added the code can you please check it .

Comment: That code doesn't give me errors when I run it from a stock Raspbian Pixel image. I only had to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-bluez` first to get it to work. I named your code `test.py` and executed it with `python test.py` I fixed indent errors, but I assume that's not present in your actual code.